# Chart js show/hide legend during runtime via buttonClick

Tags: javascript, chart.js, show-hide, legend

Hi i want to show/hide the legend of my linechart (chart.js) by clicking a button.

I tried this so far:

The following code changes the value of scatterChart.legend.options.display but after executing scatterChart.update() the value changes automatically to the initial value!

```
function showHideLegend() {
    console.log(scatterChart.legend.options.display);   // -> "inital-value" e.g.: true
    if (scatterChart.legend.options.display == true) {
        scatterChart.legend.options.display = false;
    } else {
        scatterChart.legend.options.display = true;
    }
    console.log(scatterChart.legend.options.display);   // -> value successfully changed e.g.: false
    scatterChart.update();
    //Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;     // <- does not have an effect
    console.log(scatterChart.legend.options.display);   // -> "inital-value" e.g.: true
}

function initMap() {
    scatterChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("scatterChart"), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            /*datasets: [
            ]
            */
        },
        showScale: false,
        options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
                labels: {
                    fontSize: 15
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="scatterChart" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; background-image:url('image.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;"></canvas>
<div id="scatterLegend"> //howToPutLegendHere??// </div>
<input type="button" value="Show/Hide Legend" onclick="showHideLegend()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were just trying to update the wrong legend config in the chart.js instance object.  Here is the correct way.

```
document.getElementById('hideLEgend').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // toggle visibility of legend
  myLine.options.legend.display = !myLine.options.legend.display;
  myLine.update();
});
```

The thing that you were trying to update (e.g. `chart.legend.options`) is just the default legend configuration object.  This gets merged with whatever options you define in your chart's `options.legend` config.

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/JWvGgd) showing the legend show/hide behavior from a button click.

You could also opt to not use the built in legend and generate your legend as pure HTML/CSS anywhere on your page, and then use jQuery (or standard javascript) to show and hide.  I won't provide an example for the showing/hiding (see [jQuery's show/hide functions](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)) but I will demonstrate how to generate a custom legend.  First you need to use the `options.legendCallback` option to create a function that generates the custom legend.

```
options: {
  legend: {
    display: false,
    position: 'bottom'
  },
  legendCallback: function(chart) {
    var text = [];
    text.push('<ul class="' + chart.id + '-legend">');
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
    text.push('<li><div class="legendValue"><span style="background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');

    if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
      text.push('<span class="label">' + chart.data.datasets[i].label + '</span>');
    }

    text.push('</div></li><div class="clear"></div>');
    }

    text.push('</ul>');

    return text.join('');
  }
}
```

Then use the `.generateLegend()` prototype method to generate the template (which executes the `legendCallback` function defined above) and insert it into the DOM.

```
$('#legend').prepend(mybarChart.generateLegend());
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpJjWK) that demonstrates the custom legend approach.  You can modify the `legendCallback` function to use whatever HTML you want for the legend structure and then use standard CSS to style it.  And finally, use javascript to show/hide it on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting it in a div and hide/show it with CSS? it will be present but hidden and update() will make changes to the existing data so when u want it, just remove class "hidden".

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. But i don't know how to put the legend in a seperate div (next to the div where my scatterChart is located).
Any suggestions on how to realize that?

Comment: I need more details about your code to help you with that

Comment: HTML
        <canvas id="scatterChart" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px; background-image:url('image.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;"></canvas>
    <div id="scatterLegend"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Show/Hide Legend" onclick="showHideLegend()">

JS
    function initMap() {
     scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {},
      showScale: false,
      options: {
       legend: {
        position: 'right',
        labels: {
         fontSize: 15
        }
       }
      }
     });

Comment: if your legend is in the div that has the id scatterLegend then you can easily use that id and access the div properties in javascript and manipulate with it (add or remove css class)

Comment: function initMap() {
     scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
       /*datasets: [
       ]
       */
      },
      showScale: false,
      options: {
       legend: {
        position: 'right',
        labels: {
         fontSize: 15
        }
       }
      }
     });

sorry i get confused with this editor...

Comment: that is just the code for initializing, you want to add or remove css properties on click event

Comment: my scatterChart (including its legend) is in the div id=scatterChart.
How can i put the legend of my chart into a seperate div e.g. scatterLegend?
Because i dont want to hide the whole chart.

Comment: Can you provide formatted html code when the chat is rendered in browser?